# grep in shell does not work as expected

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to search text from one file (named as `temporal3`) in another file (names as `map`) using shell's `grep` function. Here is an small part of these files:

`temporal3`:

```
TACTATATTACTGGAAAAACCATCAAGCTAGACCA
AATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAG
AGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAA
AATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAG
CTAGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAAT
AGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAAATACTGGCAAATAAT
```

`map`:

```
CTTCTGAATCCGCCAGGAGTTCTACCTCGATCAAATAATGACACTTTGCACTTGATTTTTCATCAAGAAAGTCAGTCAAATAGTTCCAGAAATGGACACAA
ATCTCACATCCCTTACTATATTACTGGAAAAACCATCAAGCTAGACCAATATAATATATCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCA
TCACATCCCTTACTATATTACTGGAAAAACCATCAAGCTAGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCACCA
AGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAAATACTGGCAAATAATCTCCTTCTGAATCCGCCAGGAGT
CCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAAATACTGGCAAATAATCTCCTTCTGAATCCGCCAGGAGTTCTACCTCGATCAAATAA
GAGATTCATCTCACATCCCTTACTATATTACTGGAAAAACCATCAAGCTAGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTA
AGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAAATACTGGCAAATAATCTCCTTCTGAATCCGCCAGGAGT
AACCATCAAGCTAGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGTTCACCAAATACTGGCAAATAATCTCCTTCTGAA
TTCATCTCACATCCCTTACTATATTACTGGAAAAACCATCAAGCTAGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGATTGCTATCGT
ATAGCGAGATTCATCTCGCATCCCTTACTATATTACTGGAAAAACCATCAAGCTAGACCAATATAATATGTCCCAGTTGAAGAGAATTATCATTTTGAGAT
```

The real `map` file is a hugh one (~20Gb) so I cannot handle it with R. What I want to do is:

1. For the first line in `temporal3`, I want to get all lines in `map` that contain it.
2. For the second line in `temporal3`, I want to get all lines in `map` that contain it.
3. ...
4. For the last line in `temporal3`, I want to get all lines in `map` that contain it.

I tried `grep -Ff temporal3 map` but it did not work! This is really surprising for me. Any idea about why this does not work? Any suggestions to get this task done? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you check your file for carriage returns? See the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) step 1.

Comment: Aha, indeed, they are in DOS style. After change them into unix style. The `grep` works. But returned one file for all lines in `temproal3` file. How can I get get one output for each line in the `temporal3`? Maybe need `for` loop? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you will need `while read` loop.

Comment: Can you give a workable code example? I am new to bash... Thanks!

Comment: `grep -Ff <(sed 's/\r$//' temporal3) map` will remove the trailing newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

> output
while read -r line; do
    grep -F "$line" map >> output
done < temporal3
```

Comment: What is the `-r` option doing here?

Comment: @DaijiangLi: `-r do not allow backslashes to escape any characters`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @anubhava ! 
This is what I want. I also changed it a little bit:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 > output
 while read -r line; do
     echo $line >> output
     grep -Fn "$line" map >> output
 done < temporal3
```